# Responsive sidebar disable on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using the following code to display a responsive sidebar that is visible upon landing, when a user scrolls to top and/or upon clicking the menu-link div too. If a user has expanded the sidebar, it will collapse again once the user has scrolled 100px up or down.

This works great on desktop, however on mobile isn't the nicest UX. I'd like to disable the part of the script that auto expands/collapses on mobile i.e <414px? I'd also like it to be hidden upon landing, i.e removing the `.active` class.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7mbck63/1/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <!-- Menu toggle -->
  <a href="#sidebar" id="sidebarToggle" class="menu-link">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </a>

  <div class="line"></div>
  <!-- Invisible line from which to measure position of #sidebar for expand/collapse purposes -->

  <div id="sidebar">
    <header>
      <h4>Sidebar Content</h4>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
/* Expand/Collapse sidebar based on position in page */
var relativeY = $("#sidebar").offset().top - $(".line").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  relativeY = $("#sidebar").offset().top - $(".line").offset().top;
  console.log(relativeY);
  if (relativeY > 100 || relativeY < -100) {
    $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
    $("#sidebarToggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".line").css("top", "0")
  } else {
    $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    $("#sidebarToggle").addClass("active");
  }
});

// Add or remove 'active' class upon landing/resize based on viewport size
(function($) {
  var $window = $(window),
    $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
  $sidebarToggle = $('#sidebarToggle');

  function resize() {
    if ($window.width() <= 768) {
      return $sidebar.removeClass('active');
      return $sidebarToggle.removeClass('active');
    }

    $sidebar.addClass('active');
    $sidebarToggle.addClass('active');
  }

  $window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);

/* Responsive sidebar */
(function(window, document) {

  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar'),
    sidebarToggle = document.getElementById('sidebarToggle');

  function toggleClass(element, className) {
    var classes = element.className.split(/\s+/),
      length = classes.length,
      i = 0;

    for (; i < length; i++) {
      if (classes[i] === className) {
        classes.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    // The className is not found
    if (length === classes.length) {
      classes.push(className);
    }

    element.className = classes.join(' ');
  }

  sidebarToggle.onclick = function(e) {
    var topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var active = 'active';
    $(".line").css("top", topScroll);
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleClass(sidebar, active);
    toggleClass(sidebarToggle, active);
  };

}(this, this.document));
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 4000px;
}


/* Sidebar */

.line {
  /* Invisible line from which to measure position of #sidebar for expand/collapse purposes */
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#sidebar {
  background: #212e37;
  color: #8b8c91;
  width: 225px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 35px;
  margin-right: -225px;
  /* "#sidebar" width */
  z-index: 9998;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-right: 0;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px) {
  #sidebar {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 75%;
    margin-right: -75%;
  }
}

#sidebar header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 40px 50px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
  color: #8b8c91;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 414px) {
  #sidebar header {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}


/* Toggle menu bar */

.menu-link {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #7e775d;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 35px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 35px 11px;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  background: #211d28;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The issue appears to be with the following piece of code, as when I remove this the mobile problem is resolved. However, I lose the functionality of adding `.active` when scrolling to the top of the page. Can the below snippit be edited to only apply if above 768px?

```
    else  {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
        $("#sidebarToggle").addClass("active");
    }
```

Comment: Simply compute the width of the window viewport using `width()` jquery method ! Side note.. Don't forget to cache jquery objects. `$("#sidebar")` and `$("#sidebarToggle")` should be defined outside from the scroll handler to prevent the DOM to be crowled (underneath using sizzle engine) each time the event occurs `:)`. Otherwise, handler may take more time to execute, (especially events triggered several times in a while like scroll, mousemove etc.) leading sometimes to laggy effects.

Comment: Hey @Stphane. I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion but I really appreciate your time. Can you offer any help? I seem to have located the issue, and have updated the question. See 'Update'. Can you shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function

```
if ($window.width() < 768) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I seem to have located the issue, and have updated the question. See 'Update'. Can you shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add a simple `if ($window.width() > 414) {}` to your JS?

```html
if ($window.width() > 414) {
  if (relativeY > 100 || relativeY < -100) {
    $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
    $("#sidebarToggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".line").css("top", "0")
  } else if ($window.width() > 768) {
    $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    $("#sidebarToggle").addClass("active");
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I like `$window.width()` more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I need to retain the scroll feature. I seem to have located the issue, and have updated the question. See 'Update'. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Well, if you want the `else` clause to only run above 768px, you could just make it an `else if ($window.width() > 768px)`. I updated the answer. I hope that helps.